# Issue with code - message is sent instantly instead of waiting for timeout to happem

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

An issue with the code - the message is sent instantly instead of waiting for the timeout to happen.

As seen in the code it should take the time mentioned in the message.
I don't understand what is happening that doesn't allow it to work at all.

```js
client.on("message", async (message) => {
    timer = false;
    if (message.content.startsWith("timer")) timer = true;

    if (timer === true) {
        timewait = message.content.slice(6);
        integertime = parseInt(timewait);
        mili = integertime * 60000;
        setTimeout(message.channel.send("messgae"), mili);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're invoking the function inside `setTimeout`, so it will run immediately. You can create a new function that returns your function like this:

```js
setTimeout(() => message.channel.send("message"), mili);
```

This way you pass a function instead of a value.

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout needs a function passed. `setTimeout(function, milliseconds)`

Try out doing `setTimeout(function(){ message.channel.send("messgae"); }, mili);`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
client.on("message", async (message) => {
 if (message.content.startsWith("timer")){
  let MessageArray = message.content.slice().trim().split(" ") // Creats an Array by seperating the Message into the Array
  let integertime = parseInt(MessageArray[1]); // Taking the second Input of your Message and parsing it into an Integer
  let mili = integertime * 60000
  setTimeout(function(){
   message.channel.send("message")
    }, mili) // Sends the Message by using the second Input you've given in your command multiplied by your value in mili as your value for the Timer.

}
})
```

See [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) in the MDN Documentation.